# Math library in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios4, math

I m trying to calculate this equation for a small iphone app:

> x = 120 x num^-1.123 x tr^-0.206 x [te] x [fe]

x equals 120 times num raised to the power of -1.123 times tr raised to the power of -0.206 times te times fe.

Where num, tr, te and fe are known numbers entered by the user.

How do I do that?
I m stuck in the negative decimal power of num and tr.

any help appreciated...

Comment: Have you tried the math.h lib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foundation will include math functions, so all you have to do is use one of the
`pow()` functions to work with. Use `pow()` for working with *doubles*, `powf()`
for *floats*, or `powl()` for long doubles. Here's an example:

```
double num = 2.0;
double tr = 3.0;
double te = 4.0;
double fe = 5.0;

double x = 120.0 * pow(num, -1.123) * pow(tr, -0.206) * te * fe;
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering how can you display an exponential number inside a string? i.e  results.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0fm^2", x]; //(m raised to the power of two)

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone SDK contains the standard C library functions (math.h) that you could use for these kind of math. Searching for math.h in your XCode documentation should show all the related functions (like pow for raising x to the power of y).